# Uncleanly exiting from C child process without valgrind complaining?

Tags: c, fork, valgrind

I have a C program which consists on one main process.

Occasionally `fork()` is used to create a parallel child process.  These exist for just a few seconds.

My main process exits nicely, unallocating all its `malloc()`'ed memory.

I want the child processes to die without unallocating all of their (parent's) `malloc()`'ed memory, as I have no clean way for them to do this.

However, Valgrind complains loudly every time a child process `exit(0)`s.

I'm using the command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --trace-children=no ./my_program
```

I've tried `--trace-children=no`.  (It should be the default, but Valgrind always traces child processes.)

Is there something I can do in code, or with switches, to make Valgrind not run on child processes?

Comment: @TonyTannous The allocated memory is only written by the parent, but the child processes use their stacks.  Assuming fork() is still Copy on Write for child processes, I can't see the relevance.

Comment: @TonyTannous A child process cannot deallocate memory of parent process.  Valgrind was complaining because the child process wasn't deallocating its copy of its parent's memory.  The child process is created with a `fork()` but is not followed by an `exec()`.

Comment: I removed comments as they were not related to your problem.

Comment: Why not have the child processes release all the memory the same as the parent does?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The child is called/forked from multiple places in the parent, therefore it cannot simply free the parents malloc'd structures and exit.  It would have to return with a flag which told the caller that this was a child process which should do no more work and just clean-up and exit.  This is a lot of complexity, which currently appears unneeded.

Comment: The child never frees the parent's memory; it frees its own (the child's own) copy (emphasize _copy_) of the memory that was allocated by the parent and bequeathed to the child when the `fork()` occurred. There'd be no need for special flags. The child is in charge of its own memory once `fork()` returns. There's no mention of shared memory; you'd need to be more careful if that was involved. But the child process could simply call the same cleanup (memory release) code as the parent process does when it exits. Or you can make Valgrind ignore the issue (as you are) — that _is_ an option too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I understand and agree about Copy on Write, you've expressed it more clearly than I could.  There is no shared memory.  After calling `function_that_forks()` the caller would need to read a flag, return-code or pid to decide whether to continue to the next operation, or immediately clean-up and exit.  I would need to put similar non-trivial logic at every call-site for `function_that_forks()`.  Is there a simpler way?  (I do agree than cleaning-up is tidier than `exit(0)`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that `--trace-children=no` only applies to `fork()`s that are followed by `exec()`.

What I needed was: `--child-silent-after-fork=yes`.